# How do I make a numerical array's increase amount smaller in each step?

Tags: javascript, arrays, math

I would like to make a numeric array  which increases in every step.

```
 [1,200,400,600,800,1000, .... , 10000]
```

But I need to make the amount by which it increases progressively smaller in every step. For example,

```
 [1, 200, 300, 350, 325, 312.5, ....., 10000]
```

If anybody knows the solution, please give me some ideas.

Thank you.

Comment: what is the progression desired?

Comment: You mean instead of the increase becoming bigger for each next element you want it to become smaller?

Comment: I think the OP wants the graph of this to look really steep at the beginning, and then level out, instead of starting fairly level and ending very steep.

Comment: Yes, Patrick. That is what I wanted to ask. Sorry for my poor explanation.

Comment: These are your increases: `2999, 2000, 1000, 500, 200, 300, 220...` They don't get smaller with each step.

Comment: @squint, the amount 'they increase each time' gets smaller.

Comment: @Brant: The list I gave above shows the increase of each step. It doesn't get smaller every time. I edited it for clarity.

Comment: Assuming you want to get the *exact* opposite rate of increase, you want to get the curve reflected around the line `y=400*x` or something similar.

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%5E3%2C+400+x%2C+%28x-20%29%5E3%2B8000%2C+0%3Cx%3C%3D20

=> Just use `y=(x-20)^3+8000` instead of `y=x^3` for the values x = 1 through 20.

I translated the negative portion of the x^3 curve to be in the first quadrant, and the rate of change looks more like what you want.

Comment: The sequence according to my description would be this: `[1141, 2168, 3087, 3904, 4625, 5256, 5803, 6272, 6669, 7000, 7271, 7488, 7657, 7784, 7875, 7936, 7973, 7992, 7999, 8000]`

Comment: Or if you want the first element to be = 1, use this: `[1, 1142, 2169, 3088, 3905, 4626, 5257, 5804, 6273, 6670, 7001, 7272, 7489, 7658, 7785, 7876, 7937, 7974, 7993, 8000]` See here (in Java) http://ideone.com/xBunXO

Comment: Mbomb007, thank you for the answer kindly. I don't need the exact rate of increasement but it definitely helps me a lot. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the increment amount as you please...

```
var arr = [];
var i = 1;
var incrementAmt = 2000;

for(var j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
    var num = i + incrementAmt;
    arr.push(num);
    i = num;
    i++;
    incrementAmt = incrementAmt / 2; // cause incrementer to decrease each iteration
}

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Thank you Brant! Your answer works as I wanted to.